# Set size of customView with a variable

Tags: android

I have a customm view which generates an arc and i've put in the xml like this

```
<com.example.application.ArcView
        android:id="@+id/arcView1"
        android:layout_width="@string/arc_size"
        android:layout_height="@string/arc_size"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

I have the height and width that change based on the screen density

I've coded it like this but it doesn't work

```
Resources res = getResources();
    String arcSizeString = res.getString(R.string.arc_size);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    switch(metrics.densityDpi){
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
             arcSize = 170;
             arcSizeString = (arcSize + "px");
                    break;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
             arcSize = 227;
             arcSizeString = (arcSize + "px");
                     break;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
             arcSize = 342;
             arcSizeString = (arcSize + "px");
                     break;
    }
```

How can i set the width and height to a variable?

Comment: FYI: By changing your `arcSizeString` value, you are NOT changing the `arc_size` value in your Resources. Resources are meant to be used _not to be modified_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, You want to ask 'how to set width and height to View'.

You need to reference instance of ArcView in your Activity class, to be more precise in onCreate method of Activity like this :

```
ArcView arcView = (ArcView)findViewById(R.id.arcView1);
```

Afther that, calculate width and height based on density and set it to your view via

```
arcView.setLayoutParams(myLayoutParams);
```

[LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: How can i give it an exact value? (i know that ldpi needs 170, mdpi 227, hdpi 342) It doesn't accept an int as value

Comment: @DoubleP90 `arcView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (arcSize, arcSize ));`